# Make bash exit != 0 when called by AWK and interrupted with ^C

Tags: bash, awk, signals, gawk

I'm having an issue with the following piece of (G)AWK script:

```
do {
    ...
} while (system("sleep 10"))
```

My intention is to break the loop when the user presses ^C during the sleep, but it's not working.

I believe the problem is that Bash exits with 0 when interrupted with ^C, at least when it's executed by AWK's `system()`:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { print "\n" system("sleep 2") }'
(let the sleep complete)
0
```

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { print "\n" system("sleep 2") }'
^C
0
```

Why is it so?

Is this a bug in Bash or in (G)AWK?

Is there a simple solution that doesn't involve complicated Bash-specific syntax like `trap`?

The best I could come up with is this:

```
do {
    ...
} while (42 == system("sleep 10 && exit 42"))
```

which still looks like a kludge to me.

Comment: You might consider perl for this job, as you can be very specific about signal handling behavior (moreso than with ruby or python).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What awk's `system()` should return [is poorly specified](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=947#c2657).

What seems to be common among `awk` implementations is that upon a normal exit, it returns the exit code (the number passed to `exit(3)` modulo 256), but when the shell process is killed by a signal, there's a lot of different behaviour.

Also note that while the C function `system(3)` is meant to ignore SIGINT (and SIGQUIT) in the parent, it's not very clear (to me at least) that the requirement also applies to `awk`'s `system()`. Some `awk` implementations (like `mawk`) will die upon that SIGINT (that's also the behaviour I'd like to see as I don't like my CTRL-C being ignored just because `awk` happens to be running the `system()` function), some (like `gawk` or traditional implementations) won't.

Also note that some shells can intercept some of those signals and eventually call `exit()` which would affect the behaviour (see the discussion in comments about the Bourne shell for instance), which is why I use `exec` in the examples below to remove the shell from the loop.

For the value returned by `system()` (there's even more variation if you consider `close()`<sup>1</sup>) upon a SIGINT, we see:

```
$ nawk 'BEGIN {print system("exec kill -s INT $$")}'
0.0078125
$ bwk-awk 'BEGIN {print system("exec kill -s INT $$")}'
0.0078125
$ mawk 'BEGIN {print system("exec kill -s INT $$")}'
130
$ gawk 'BEGIN {print system("exec kill -s INT $$")}'
0
```

`0.0078125` being `2 / 256` (for a `SEGV` of `11`, you'd get 0.542969 ((128+11)/256) if a core was dumped, 0.0429688 (11/256) otherwise), `nawk` being the `nawk` found on Solaris 10 or 11, or its Linux port in the Heirloom toolchest, `bwk-awk` being [the `awk` maintained by Brian Kernighan himself](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~bwk/btl.mirror/) (the `K` in `awk`) the basis for the `awk` found on some BSDs (here tested on Debian GNU/Linux). `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` on Solaris 11 behaves like `gawk`.

So based on the value `s` returned by `system(3)` (an integer where bits 0 to 6 are the signal number, bit 7 the core-bit, and bits 8 to 15 the exit code), `awk`'s `system()` above returns either:

- `s / 256` (traditional `awk` implementations),
- `int(s/256)` (`gawk`),
- or in `mawk`, the same transformation as done by shells like the Bourne or C-shell for instance (`(s&127)+128` if killed, `s>>8` otherwise), except that if a core is dumped, you get `(s&127)+256` instead of `(s&127)+128` (the value is `(s&255)+128`).

So, here, you could do instead:

```
awk 'BEGIN{print system("trap exit\\ 1 INT; sleep 10")}'
```

But it would still cause `awk` to be killed with some `awk` implementations like `mawk`. If your `sh` is `bash` or `yash`, you could do:

```
awk 'BEGIN{print system("set -m; sleep 10; exit")}'
```

So `sleep` is run in its own process group (and only it gets the SIGINT).

Another alternative could be to ignore SIGINT before calling `awk`. However, most shells (and that's a POSIX requirement) cannot change a signal handler if the signal was already ignored on start. So things like:

```
(
  trap '' INT
  awk 'BEGIN{print system("trap exit\\ 1 INT; sleep 10; exit")}'
)
```

Won't work. `zsh` doesn't have that (self-inflicted) limitation though, so if you know `zsh` is available, you could do:

```
(
  trap '' INT
  awk 'BEGIN{print system("exec zsh -c \"TRAPINT() exit 1; sleep 10\"")}'
)
```

Which would work whether `awk` is `mawk`, `gawk` or other and would avoid having to mess with job control. At this point though, it would be worth considering using `perl`/`python`/`ruby`... instead of `awk` where you can adapt the signal handling to your needs.

### Notes

<sup>1</sup> Upon `close()` of a pipeline, as in:

```
awk 'BEGIN {cmd = "kill -s INT $$"; cmd | getline; print close(cmd)}'
```

First, this time `^C` interrupts `awk` in all implementations I've tried (there's not such requirement to ignore SIGINT/SIGQUIT for `popen(3)`/`pclose(3)` (a natural way to implement that `getline`) as there is for `system(3)`).

But when it comes to the exit status (where `s` is the value returned by `pclose(3)`/`waitpid(2)` like for `system()` above), we see:

- Solaris `nawk`: doesn't work, you can't call `close()` like that in Solaris `nawk`.
- `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` on Solaris. Returns always 0, even upon a `exit(1)` done by the process. Clearly a conformance bug.
- `gawk` and `bwk-awk`: gives `s` (`exit 1` gives 256, killed by SIGINT gives 2, killed by a SIGSEGV of 11 with core gives 139).
- `mawk`: same as for `system()`, looks like `mawk` is the only implementation that gave any thought into that.

Comment: Poorly specified or not, it looks like a bug in GAWK to me. Oh well. Thanks

Comment: Also, `set -m` by itself seems to do the trick! `system("set -m; sleep 10")` is actually the cleanest solution of the bunch, and it works reliably across all AWKs. Awesome!

Comment: @Tobia. Yes, happens to work with `yash` as well. Note that that usage of `set -m` is not portable (won't work with other implementations of `sh` that I know). And it will prevent you from running `awk` in background.

Comment: You're right. It doesn't work with Dash, which is the default `/bin/sh` in many systems :-(

Comment: Looks like you are not using the original `nawk` but something else.

Comment: @schily, that was with the `nawk` found in Solaris 11 or the Heirloom toolchest. I don't have access to any other `nawk`. Did earlier versions of `awk` behave differently?

Comment: This is really strange, `nawk` on Solaris used to print 208 with your sample code, but it seems that this changed after the Bourne Shell was replaced by ksh93. At least there are no relevant changes in the source since 2007 but a version from 2009 prints 208. BTW: `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` prints 130 on Solaris. OK, found the reason 208 is 2000 % 256 - the Bourne Shell exits with 2000 from an internal signal and system() returns the full status int from waitpid(). So this is a problem from a wrong system() implementation and we need to find what happened to OpenSolaris b147.

Comment: Just a note: system() on UNIX used to return 256 * (exitcode % 256). This is why awk divides the system return code by 256.

Comment: @schily, that's what I say in the answer (bits 0 to 7 the signal, bit 8 for dumped cores, bits 8 to 15 for exit code). On what Unix-like system is it not the case?

Comment: OK, so the difference seems to be that Bourne Shell catches the signal and then exit()s with an intentional exit code of 2000 while ksh93 does not catch the signal and thus wait() from system() really sees a process that died from a signal and return just 2. Then values below 1 inside awk are really possible but confusing because they depend on the shell in use.

Comment: @schily, yes, `truss` on Solaris 10 seems to confirm what you're saying. So it would seem my answer is correct, just the test case (`nawk 'BEGIN{print system("kill $$")}'`) should be changed when `system()` invokes the Bourne shell that calls exit() when killed. I'll change to `system("exec kill $$")` to remove the shell from the loop.

Comment: This will not always do what you indent, as /usr/bin/kill may be a script wrapper around the system shell and not a plain binary.

Comment: @schily. True. That works here though on Solaris 10 as `/bin/kill` is a `ksh` script and not a `sh` one, so it at least fixes the Solaris problem. Since most other systems no longer use the Bourne shell, we can hope it will work there too...