# how to get the stated behaviour for awk's system() command?

Tags: shell-script, awk, exit

I'm calling the sleep command from awk like so: `system("sleep 15m")` and found that when I interrupt that with CTRL-C it only interrupts the sleep command, not the script. So I tried wrapping the system function in an if statement, as suggested [in this sample script](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Alarm-Program.html) and further explained [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/I_002fO-Functions.html#index-system_0028_0029-function). It then looks like `if (system("sleep 15m") != 0) exit 1`.

That didn't work, so I tried `print system("sleep 3")`, which always returns 0, contrary to the stated behavior. Typing `sleep 3` then `echo $?` in the shell produces 0 if I let it run and 130 if I interrupt it.

So what am I missing? I've checked for typos several times, tried the --posix and --traditional switches, and studied the user's guide, nothing changes it.

```
$ awk --version
GNU Awk 4.1.3, API: 1.1 (GNU MPFR 3.1.4, GNU MP 6.1.0)
Copyright (C) 1989, 1991-2015 Free Software Foundation.
```

Comment: Have you tried using `kill` or `pkill` to send specific signals to the `sleep` process directly, rather than relying on your terminal emulator's handling of Ctrl-C?  That would at least eliminate one variable if it still returns 0 (or isolate the cause if it produces 130 or other).

Comment: `print system("sleep 3")` when killed should return 258 according to the docs, which it does on my system. It may depend on how your `sh` behaves, as system() is the equivalent of `sh -c 'sleep 3'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Appears to be a gawk bug**

```
$ echo foo | gawk '{print system("sleep 3")}'
^C0
$
```

Seems related to [Make bash exit != 0 when called by AWK and interrupted with ^C](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/267415/make-bash-exit-0-when-called-by-awk-and-interrupted-with-c)

**gawk workaround, courtesy of Keith**

```
$ echo foo | awk '{if(system("sleep 3 && exit 42")==42){print "completed"}else{print "interrupted"}}'
completed
$ echo foo | awk '{if(system("sleep 3 && exit 42")==42){print "completed"}else{print "interrupted"}}'
^Cinterrupted
$
```

**nawk handles it correctly**

```
$ echo foo | nawk '{print system("sleep 3")}'
^C0.0078125
$
```

Comment: Well, nawk on my system seems to be a symlink to gawk; but the related question details the problem quite nicely. I don't know why I couldn't find that one.

Comment: so `if( system("sleep 3 && exit 42" ) != 42 ) exit 1` seems to work nicely as a workaround.

Comment: Good idea, have added your workaround to the main body of the answer.